# Non-standard logins

Tags: ssh, character-encoding, putty

As part of a sort of esoteric "hack" I'm putting together, I've modified my `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files to result in a user called `ニエット` ("Niet") with a shell pointing to a custom script I have written.

This all works great, and I can do:

```
ssh ニエット@localhost
```

Enter the password, log in, and I get the output of my custom script (currently just "Hello, World!", wait five seconds, then disconnect).

It works beautifully!

There's only one problem. I can't seem to SSH in directly from tools like PuTTY. In fact, the only way I've been able to connect is by SSHing in to my normal user, then doing the `ssh` to `localhost` as above.

I have tried putting `ニエット@example.com` in the "hostname" field and similarly in the "autologin username" option, but both result in trying to log in as `????` which obviously fails. This is in spite of ensuring the character encoding is set to UTF-8.

Similarly, I've tried not using auto-login, but... well...

```
login as: ▒▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒@example.com's password:
Access denied
```

Not *quite* what I'm after.

**I am well aware that what I have done with this username is a complete hack and I should probably be hit with a brick for it.** But it *does* work, I just seem to be having a problem with my computer's PuTTY communicating with the server, since the server is perfectly able to communicate with itself.

Am I missing an option or something to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because you need to have a compatible character set on both sides. Since the SSH username isn't established based on *glyphs*, but on the actual real binary value.

The best suggestion I can give is to try to use UTF-8 on both sides. Use a hex editor to display the hex values on the windows side and on the unix side. Make sure they match. If they don't then it *can't* work.

But more generally, what exactly are you trying to do? If you're trying to make a "secret" user, you'd be much better off (and more secure) to create an ordinary use with a 7-bit ascii user name with a disabled password and a **key** for logins.

Comment: The intention is to be a sort of easter-egg. It would be presented as a thing like "haha, with a username like ニエット I don't even need a password!" -- "But you have to put something. Lemme guess, it's `password`" -- "Don't be silly, it's notpassword" (with the lack of a space being the hint to it being, literally, `notpassword`). I'm using a custom script as the shell so it can't actually do anything except navigate the minigame. If a UTF-8 username isn't possible, I suppose I'll have to go for a more "standard" username and "accidentally" publish the password.